# Shaped charges/explosive lenses and implosion in the Fat Man design for the Nuclear Bomb: how do these actually cause implosion?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, nuclear-physics, lenses, nuclear-engineering, explosions

This is gone into at some length but not much detail (that I could understand) in "The Making of the Atomic Bomb" by Rhodes. The basic story is that the Americans were having trouble getting implosion tests to work at all; they tried in in 2D with a ring of explosives around a pipe and the pipe did not collapse as wanted into a solid metal bar because the explosion was not uniform. Then a British scientist named Tuck suggested explosive lenses to focus the blast and eventually it all worked.

My question is, with multiple lenses, unless the explosions were synchronized within I think it was a microsecond, you would not get an implosion anyway.

So what was the purpose of the lenses? Was it

1. To make a given explosion more uniform?
2. To make the lack of perfect synchronization less critical? (You could never get perfect synchronization.)
3. Something else?

Comment: @Qmechanic: your edit is wrong -- please revert the wrong parts.

Answer (score 2):

The detonation wave that is initiated from any single point in a solid explosive is an expanding sphere.  The lenses literally work like optical lenses. They are made from the precisely shaped interface between two different explosive compounds with different detonation velocities--just like how optical lenses are are made by the interface between optical media with different refractive indices.

The lenses in a nuclear weapon are shaped to change the expanding spherical waves from many seperate initiators into a single *collapsing* spherical wave that is centered on the core.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosive_lens

Comment: but the need for synchronization remains, right?

Comment: @releseabe, Absolutely! In fact, it's considered a "safety" feature. If the initiators aren't all fired within some very tight time window (on the order of microseconds, I think, but I'm not sure) then the weapon will self-destruct without producing any significant nuclear "yield." Expensive mess to clean up though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966_Palomares_B-52_crash